# Group non-static class properties

Tags: c#, .net, properties, non-static

I'm writing a .Net library and this is my scenario:
I have a "Manager" class that contains a List of "Batches". Every batch has a Status property.

```
public class Batch
{
 public string Status { get { return batchActualStatusVar; } }
}
```

BatchManager has an enumerator, whose keys are equal to possible batch statuses.

```
public enum BatchStatus
{
 Completed = 64,
 Error = 32,
 InProgress = 4
 And so on.....
}
```

I created properties in BatchManager that allow me to divide Batches according to them Status, like this:

```
public List<Batch> BatchesCompleted { 
   get { 
   return Batches.Where(x => x.Status == BatchManager.BatchStatus.Completed.ToString()).ToList(); } }
```

**Question**
In which way can I group properties to have a structure like this:

```
BatchManager
    PropertiesGroup
           BatchesCompleted
           BatchesReady
           ....
```

I tried with a struct inside BatchManager class, but the problem is that "Batches" in BatchManager isn't static and I cannot access them from inside the struct.
I cannot use other class for the same reason.

(This isn't a specific question, it is only an example to make question simple to understand)

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `BatchFilter` class that is returned by the property `PropertiesGroup` and that is built with information coming from the `BatchManager`

```
public class BatchFilter
{
    private List<Batch> _batches;
    public BatchFilter(List<Batch> batches)
    {
         _batches = batches;
    }

    public List<Batch> BatchesCompleted { 
   get { 
   return _batches.Where(x => x.Status == BatchManager.BatchStatus.Completed.ToString()).ToList(); } }
}

class BatchManager
{
    public BatchFilter PropertiesGroup { get { return new BatchQuery(Batches); }}
    // ...
}
```

If you want you can cache it, reset it when Batches change, etc...